# SetInterval() with React doesn't work as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

In my react project I need to use `setInterval()`, but instead of repeatedly launching is launch only one time. (Pseudo code below) . Does anyone know how fix this? In other stackoverflow questions I doesn't find what I need.

```js
/*---- React Component ----*/
class Grid extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(timeline.launch(), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GridView />
    )
  }
}

/*---- Timeline Function ----*/

const $ = window.$;

class lifeTimeline {
  launch() {
    $(document).ready(function() { /* Render Timer on the screen */ }
      
  }
}

const instance = new lifeTimeline();
export default instance;
```

Comment: Javascript issue: unless timeline.launch() returns a function, you want `setInterval(timeline.launch, 1000);` and more likely `setInterval(instance.launch, 1000);` but then again you would not want each second add an onload handler after onload: `$(document).ready(function() { /* Render Timer on the screen */ }`

Comment: "_In other stackoverflow questions I doesn't find what I need_" [No?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542207/setinterval-fires-only-once)

Comment: @Teemu, )) I searched with other keywords

Comment: @mplungjan, then what I should do ? Is it possible somehow set if statement

Comment: componentDidMount is enough. Just insert the timer value in launch

Comment: Your search case implements very well, how useful it is to write "_it doesn't work_" to a post. Please get rid of it, and describe the real problem instead in the title too.

Answer (score -1):

setInterval requires a function object, but you are **calling** launch.
move setInterval inside launch, and then you can call launch inside componentDidMount