# Using signalR with a javascript timer in an MVC 5 web application Memory consumption / how to

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, timer, signalr, stopwatch

I'm using maček's answer from this post [How to create a stopwatch using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318822/how-to-create-a-stopwatch-using-javascript) to create javascript timers in an HTML table for each tr.

When someone starts the timer I would like it to be available for everyone else looking at that same tr element that may be on the page at a different computer.

I'm very new to signalR and have only played with some examples. What I'd like to know is "Is this possible", if so how? And if I had 1,000 timers going would this consume a lot of server memory?

The timer is not stored in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How will you determin if a user "looks" at a TR? If its focused?

Anyway, when you solve that just send a message to the server and let the server boradcast that using SignalR, no need for timers imo.

I think my SignalR pub/Sub library can be of use for you, have a look here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Comment: I think you're right. No need for timers. Thank you for the resources! I'm going to boot up that demo project and do some more learning.  The "looks" at a TR just meant that they had the page open with the table loaded. So they'd be looking at all or any timer that had been started.