# Jquery Mobile stopwatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Im trying to make a stopwatch in a JqueryMobile app. I've been following the guide from a previous post  [How to create a stopwatch using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318822/how-to-create-a-stopwatch-using-javascript)

This works but the function to create the button, essential just makes 3 links, where as I want them as buttons. So at present it will generate the html of:

```
<a href="#start" class="ui-link">start</a>
```

where as I need it to be

```
<a href="#start" data-role="button" class="ui-link">start</a>
```

I've played around with the function to try to get it to work, and even just added my own buttons into the HTML with hrefs of #start, #stop, #reset but cant get them to work

The function is:

```
function createButton(action, handler) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "#" + action;
    a.innerHTML = action;
    a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        handler();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    return a;
}
```

Comment: How are you using/calling `createButton()`? Anything like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pxb6rarx/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the classes `ui-btn ui-btn-inline` to the links in createButton. As you are using jQuery anyway, I hvae also updated the stopwatch to use jQuery for DOM manipulation:

```
(function($) {
    var Stopwatch = function (elem, options) {

      var timer = createTimer(),
        startButton = createButton("start", start),
        stopButton = createButton("stop", stop),
        resetButton = createButton("reset", reset),
        offset,
        clock,
        interval;

      // default options
      options = options || {};
      options.delay = options.delay || 1;

      var $elem = $(elem);

      // append elements     
      $elem.empty()
           .append(timer)
           .append(startButton)
           .append(stopButton)
           .append(resetButton);


      // initialize
      reset();

      // private functions
      function createTimer() {
        return $('<span class="swTime"></span>');
      }

      function createButton(action, handler) {
        var a = $('<a class="' + action + ' ui-btn ui-btn-inline">' + action + '</a>');
        a.on("click",function (event) {
          handler();
          event.preventDefault();
        });    
        return a;
      }

      function start() {
        if (!interval) {
          offset = Date.now();
          interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
        }
      }

      function stop() {
        if (interval) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = null;
        }
      }

      function reset() {
        clock = 0;
        render();
      }

      function update() {
        clock += delta();
        render();
      }

      function render() {
        timer.text(clock / 1000);
      }

      function delta() {
        var now = Date.now(),
          d = now - offset;

        offset = now;
        return d;
      }

      // public API
      this.start = start;
      this.stop = stop;
      this.reset = reset;
    };

    $.fn.stopwatch = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(idx, elem) {
          new Stopwatch(elem, options);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
    $(".stopwatch").stopwatch();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/re71o98o/2/)**

Comment: Firstly, don't decorate links by placing them in blockquotes. Secondly, you should post the code you've changed in the answer and link to the JSFiddle demo if you still feel that's necessary, otherwise this answer will be meaningless if JSFiddle goes offline.

Comment: This is great thanks I've got it work on my page now, I'm attempting to put the timer into a text box to make it look better.
it works if I use:

     <textarea id="countDisplay" class="swTime" disabled></textarea>

but not if I use (which I want to):

     <input type="text" id="countDisplay" class="swTime"/>

Comment: @user3346481, change the render function to use val() instead of text(): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/re71o98o/6/